# Is it possible to have php load and run Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php script that runs glob on a directory, and it returns all the images it finds in the directory, with an ad from google before all the images.
I would like it if I could use glob to load 10 of the images, then insert the javascript from googles ad services, and continue loading the images. So an ad every 10 images. Every attempt by me so far has failed spectacularly, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is my PHP code

```
<?php
$manualwidth = $_GET['manwidth'];
$manualdir = $_GET['mandir'];
$manualmodel = $_GET['manurl'];
$manualurl = $manualdir . '/' . $manualmodel . '/';
$files = glob($manualurl .'{*.jpg,*.gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)


{
    $num = $files[$i];
    echo '<img src="'.$num.'" width="'.$manualwidth.'"><br>'."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Read. Learn. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack

Comment: How do you currently insert the ad?

Comment: I'm not really sure what this has to do with running Javascript from PHP, or why you would think that would be beneficial for your end result. Seems to me that you just want to output an adv. every 10 images, which should be `spectacularly` easy.

Comment: please don't count() every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Echo the js every 10th iteration

```
<?php
$count = count($files);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
    if($i % 10 === 0) {
      echo "google ads here";
    }
    $num = $files[$i];
    echo '<img src="'.$num.'" width="'.$manualwidth.'"><br>'."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
?>
```

Comment: Or, array_chunk x elements and create a new array with the ad and the chunks.

Comment: @Panagiotis He'd still have to iterate over the new array, so what's the point?

Comment: i'll take simplicity over elegance any day

Comment: The real goal is to find an elegant, yet simple solution.

Comment: and that is what makes it art ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the ad code into an html file in the directory:

**ad.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript>
//Code to run
</script>
//other ad stuff here
```

And then just include that file after every 10 images:

**index.php**

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= count($files); $i++)
{
    //Echo image code here

    if($i%10 == 0)
    include("ad.html");

}
```